# I have a problem with adding surfaces

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

[image: image of the blender model]

Hi I'm trying to make the surface of the object smooth

I tried 'shade smooth' on both object/edit mode.
However, I couldn't get the result as I wanted.

just like the illustration on the right,
I want the head piece to be smooth
it's polygonal and rough at the moment.

I also tried 'bevel'
but it still left the existence of the original edge

and lastly, the 'subdivision modifier'
gave me the closest result that I want.

but It also modified the surfaces that I didn't want them to be.

to make it smooth, do you have any suggestion?

just like bevel, I think if there's any other technique for adding
surfaces, that might help

Comment: hello please share your file (at least the part that you want to smooth): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for your aid. I have sent the file. please take a look

Comment: the url of the blender file you mean? So rry I'm new to this community. All I did was just go to the link link you shared and upload the blender file and the link of this question

Comment: yes then it gives you a URL that you need to copy and paste here

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=OLpAznAQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/OLpAznAQ/)

Comment: Alright! so I've sent the file just the headpiece cuz the original file was too big that it didn't send me the URL

Comment: So what you need to do is give a Subdivision Surface modifier, then add some edge loops close to the angles that need to stay sharp

Comment: I tried subvide modifier. What's left to do is to add edge loop but..... I'm not so sure how to keep some edges sharp

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. As it will round the angles that you want to keep sharp, you'll have to add some edge loops close to these angles.

To make things easier you must try to keep a good edge flow. This [site](https://topologyguides.com/) (topologyguides) gives some good tricks but in my opinion the more you'll try the more you'll succeed.

Here is a quick example of what you could do:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this will work! much obliged

Comment: There's no magic trick for sharp edges, each case will be different and sometimes it's hard to solve, but that's the way to go